# Python regexp. My small program it is impossible to distinguish letters from numbers

Tags: regex, python-2.7, coordinates, match

Given the coordinates of the polygon and have to check the input string containing the data coordinates.
Here is my code

```
import re

t = "(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(0,1)"
#tt = "(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(0,'a')"

p='((\([0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*,(\s)*[0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*\)(\s)*,?(\s)*)+)'
b=re.search(p,t)
if b: 
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

In both cases (t and tt) , the function returns true. Why is it so

Comment: Many thanks to all who responded to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add anchors. RE can match anywhere in your string

`p='^((\([0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*,(\s)*[0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*\)(\s)*,?(\s)*)+)$'`

```
>>> import re
>>> t = "(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(0,1)"
>>> p='((\([0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*,(\s)*[0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*\)(\s)*,?(\s)*)+)'
>>> re.search(p, t)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE7E20>
>>> tt = "(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(0,'a')"
>>> re.search(p, tt)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE7E90>
>>> p='^((\([0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*,(\s)*[0-9]+.?[0-9]*(\s)*\)(\s)*,?(\s)*)+)$'
>>> re.search(p, tt)
>>>  #no matching!
```

The `^` matches the start and the `$` matches the end. This make the matching string **only** contains paired number from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 0):

That big subexpression is supposed to match an ordered pair (with an optional comma at the end), and I think it does.  The + just means "one or more"; tt has four of them, and four is more than one, so the expression gets matched (with those four points as the match).  If you want your pattern to match the whole string, then you need begin and end anchors in there, i.e. `^` and `$`.